# angular flex-layout error : has no exported member ɵNgClassImpl error

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

In my last Mean stack project I used angular flex layout and it was working fine

I started a new project with angular 7 including flex layout 8(beta) and got the following error

```
    ERROR in 
    node_modules/@angular/flexlayout/extended/typings/class/class.d.ts(9,19): 
    error TS2305: Module '".../.../node_modules/@angular/common/common"' 
    has no exported member 'ɵNgClassImpl'
```

This is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
   "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.25",
   "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
   "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
   "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
   "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
   "core-js": "^2.5.4",
   "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
   "jquery": "^3.4.1",
   "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
   "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
   "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
   "tslib": "^1.9.0",
   "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
 },
```

can any one explain why this is happening? It works fine with flex-layout 7.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flex Layout v8 only works with Angular v8. Go back to V7

Comment: yes. thanks for the clarification. flex layout v7 only works with angular v7 and flex v6 with angular6. its been like that

Comment: Or you can fix by this
npm install @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24

Answer (score 13):

**For Angular 9**

Install the 9.x version of flex-layout

```
npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@9.0.0-beta.29
```

Add needed dependency:

```
npm install tslib --save
```

See
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md